# Android Studio Spinner causing app to crash before it even opens

Tags: java, android

[dropbox link on the project folder](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/o7ntkaa1tm49x6u/AAD3HL8kiDM_g0XE_9ejqVSxa?dl=0)

Whenever i run the app in the android studio emulator it automatically crashes. can anyone help me with what errors have i done here? here is just the specific spinner code. but the link has the app.

```
List < String > empSale = new ArrayList < String > ();
empSale.add("Sale Items:");
empSale.add("Apple iPhone 8");
empSale.add("Samsung Galaxy 9");
empSale.add("Asus Zenfone 10");
empSale.add("Nokia 3310");

spnSale = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnSale);
spnSale.setOnItemSelectedListener((AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) this);

//Spinner data
aA = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, empSale);
aA.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spnSale.setAdapter(aA);

spnSale.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView << ? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    String items = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected " + items, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (items.equals("Sale Items:")) {
      //price = 0;
      txtPrice.setText("Price: Php 0.00");
    }
    if (items.equals("Apple iPhone 8")) {
      //price = 60000;
      txtPrice.setText("Price: Php 60000.00");
    }
    if (items.equals("Samsung Galaxy 9")) {
      //price = 55000;
      txtPrice.setText("Price: Php 55000.00");
    }
    if (items.equals("Asus Zenfone 10")) {
      //price = 50000;
      txtPrice.setText("Price: Php 50000.00");
    }
    if (items.equals("Nokia 3310")) {
      //price = 1000000;
      txtPrice.setText("Price: Php 1000000.00");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: What's the error. Do you have a crash log in logcat?

Comment: try using `aA = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, empSale);`

Comment: @litelite it doesnt show any crash errors

Comment: Never mind all i had to do was Remove the `aA.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);` below the `aA = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, empSale);`

Answer (score 0):

Never mind all i had to do was Remove the `aA.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);` below the `aA = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, empSale);`

Answer (score 0):

Simple
Just remove your spinner on item click listener because onItemClick listener does not work on Spinners.

```
       spnSale = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnSale);

       spnSale.setOnItemSelectedListener((AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) this);

     //Spinner data
     aA = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, 
     android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, empSale);


   aA.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spnSale.setAdapter(aA);


   String item = spnSale.getItemSelected().toString();
if (items.equals("Sale Items:")) {
  //price = 0;
  txtPrice.setText("Price: Php 0.00");
}else
if (items.equals("Apple iPhone 8")) {
  //price = 60000;
  txtPrice.setText("Price: Php 60000.00");
}else
if (items.equals("Samsung Galaxy 9")) {
  //price = 55000;
  txtPrice.setText("Price: Php 55000.00");
}else
if (items.equals("Asus Zenfone 10")) {
  //price = 50000;
  txtPrice.setText("Price: Php 50000.00");
}else
if (items.equals("Nokia 3310")) {
  //price = 1000000;
  txtPrice.setText("Price: Php 1000000.00");
}
  ....
  ....
```

Try this